# How to truncate a string's length to the largest multiple of a smaller integer?

Tags: python, string, truncate

I have a string `path` of arbitrary length, and an integer `x` that's less than or equal to than the length of `path`. I want to truncate `path`'s length to the largest multiple of `x` that is less or equal to `path`'s original length.

Here's the best I've been able to come up with, but I feel like Python would have a better way to do this:

```
final_length = 0
while final_length + x <= len(path):
    final_length = final_length + x
final_path = path[:final_length]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer division will give you want without using a loop

```
x = 3
s = 'hello world'

s[:(len(s) // x) * x]
```

returns

```
hello wor
```

which has length 9

Comment: Alternative form that might do (slightly) less work: `s[:-(len(s) % x) or None]`

Comment: Nice one @ShadowRanger!

Comment: Thank you! I *knew* there was a more elegant way to do this, but I couldn't quite place my finger on it.